# Neo4j performance on single node insertion and fetching

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I just running a simple insertion query in Enterprise version **neo4j-3.1.3** on neo4j browser. At the very first time insertion execution time is 410ms, and subsequent insertion it reduce to 4ms.

**CQL:**

```
create (n:City {name:"Trichy", lat:50.25, lng:12.21});
//Execution Time : Completed after 410 ms.
```

Even fetching a single node taking much time.

**My CQL Query**:

```
MATCH (n:City) RETURN n LIMIT 25
//Execution time : Started streaming 1 record after 105 ms and completed after 111 ms
```

I have allotted:  `dbms.memory.pagecache.size=15g`

System:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         11121       8171       2950        611        956       2718
-/+ buffers/cache:       4496       6625
Swap:         3891          0       3891
```

1. Why its taking much time on singe insertion. Even **4ms** seems too costly for a single insertion with minimal property.
2. Even fetching also taking much time.

Comment: What disk are you using, an SSD or an HDD? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: You have tagged this with spring-data-neo4j and neo4j-ogm. Are you using those layers in this test?

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas Using HDD. 12GB RAM. Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @InverseFalcon No.. This test layer i didnt use spring-data-neo4j and ogm. But I tried the same test with SDN & ogm, The execution time these query is almost taking **double of the execution time**

Comment: Can you clarify that? It's hard to tell apart the execution times you're comparing. Also, keep in mind your creation query also includes setting up and tearing down the transaction and writing to the label index. That said, try performing tests using graph queries. If you just need to perform simple inserts and retrieves, then you don't need a graph db. If you do need a graph db, test it for the type of graph queries you need. Lastly, is there a reason you're using 3.1.3? That's nearly two minor versions back. 3.3.0 was just released, and if you don't want a .0 release try the latest 3.2.x.

Comment: Please Let me explain by code..

Comment: @InverseFalcon `for(int i=1;i<=1;i++){ AirportStation airport = new AirportStation("Airport - " + i);
List<TrainStation> listTrain = new ArrayList<>();
for(int j=1;j<=10;j++){
TrainStation train = new TrainStation("Train - " + j);
listTrain.add(train);
airport.setTrainStation(listTrain);
 List<Interest> listInterest = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int k=1; k<=100; k++) {
 Interest interest = new Interest("MyInterest - " + k);
 listInterest.add(interest);
 train.setInterest(listInterest);
 session.save(airport);
}}`**This execution taking almost 8min to complete" which is too expensive**

Comment: OGM layer typically won't perform as well as a plain cypher query, but 8 minutes does seem far too excessive for something like this. You may want to check on the neo4j-users slack, asking on the #neo4j-sdn-ogm channel, or ask a separate question for that code.

Comment: @InverseFalcon thanks a lot.. The code is mentioning  An airport station connecting with 10 train station and each train station connecting with 100 Places(interest).., Totally 1011 record is inserted at  the end of execution. Let me put the same query on **slack**